android java how to extract data from json request from telegram api link
i created app for forwarding sms to telegram group chat
app design
i want app get chat [groupid & title] dynamically from api link
https://api.telegram.org/bot<YourBOTToken>/getUpdates

when i click button (get chat id) then execute the link and get chat id from json result.
{
    "update_id": 8393,
    "message": {
        "message_id": 3,
        "from": {
            "id": 7474,
            "first_name": "AAA"
        },
        "chat": {
            "id": <group_ID>,
            "title": "<Group name>"
        },
        "date": 25497,
        "new_chat_participant": {
            "id": 71, 
            "first_name": "NAME",
            "username": "YOUR_BOT_NAME"
        }
    }
}

i used volley request
private void getChatId() {

    botToken = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.botToken);

    telegramApiUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot"+botToken.getText().toString()+"/getUpdates";

    JsonArrayRequest request = new JsonArrayRequest(com.android.volley.Request.Method.GET, telegramApiUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {

                for(int i=0; i < response.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = jsonObject.getString("chat").toString();
                    String idUser = jsonObject.getString("id").toString();

                    resultToken.setText(id);
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                resultV.setText(e.toString());
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);

}

and i want to extract chat => id and chat => title from api json result as i showed before
done solved using gson lib, ty.

done solved using gson lib, ty.
